# Given a Swift `Any` type can I determine if it's an `Optional`?

Tags: swift

Given a value of type `Any` is it possible to check and see if it's an Optional or not?
This code doesn't work because instead of checking to see if it's optional or not it's trying to cast it, and it passes

```
let a: Any = "5"

switch a {
case let optional as Optional<Any>:
    if case .some(let value) = optional {
        print("wrapped value of `\(a)` is `\(value)`")
    }

default:
    print("\(a) is not an optional")
}
```

---

Base on @dfri's solution

```
private func isOptional(input: Any) -> Bool {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: input)
    let style = mirror.displayStyle

    switch style {
    case .some(.optional):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to check at run time if a variable is optional ? Usually you already know what to expect when you look at the code. I'm not saying you do something wrong, just want to know.

Comment: In your code, `a` is _typed_ as Any. Therefore it can _never_ be `Optional<Any>`.

Comment: @matt I think the op is wondering the the value _wrapped by the non-optional `Any` instance_ is an optional or not (not that I have any idea what this would be useful for).

Comment: @matt see "another example" from my answer ...

Comment: @bogdanf writing an auto swift serializer which needs to unwrap the value of optionals before adding them to a dictionary https://gist.github.com/aryaxt/339547363e5caae9dcd9ef6b67a55724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use runtime introspection using [`Mirror`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror):

```
let foo: String? = "foo"
let bar: String = "bar"
var a: Any = foo

// if wrapping an optional, the reflection of the value has
// a displaystyle "optional"
if let displayStyle = Mirror.init(reflecting: a).displayStyle {
    print(displayStyle) // optional
}

// for a non-optional fundamental native type: no displaystyle
a = bar
if let displayStyle = Mirror.init(reflecting: a).displayStyle {
    print(displayStyle)
} // prints nothing
```

Optional/non-optional example where the underlying type is user-defined (non native):

```
struct Foo {}
let foo: Foo? = Foo()
let bar: Foo = Foo()
var a: Any = foo

// if wrapping an optional, the reflection of the value has
// a displaystyle "optional"
if let displayStyle = Mirror(reflecting: a).displayStyle {
    print(displayStyle) // optional
}

// for a non-optional non-fundamental type:
a = bar
if let displayStyle = Mirror(reflecting: a).displayStyle {
    print(displayStyle) // struct
}
```

If you don't want need to use the binded `displayStyle` variable (e.g. for printing) but simply want check whether the wrapped value is any kind of optional, you can add a boolean clause to the `if` statement that holds the optional binding of the `displayStyle` case,

```
if let displayStyle = Mirror(reflecting: a).displayStyle,
    displayStyle == .optional {
    // is an optional ...
}
```

... or remove the binding entirely in favour of a single conditional expression using the nil coalescing operator (`??`)

```
if Mirror(reflecting: a).displayStyle ?? .class == .optional {
    // is an optional
}
```

Note however that for all the methods above, this simply tells you as dev whether the type wrapped by the `Any` instance is optional or not: Swifts typing system still knows nothing of the sort.

Comment: thanks, using displayStyle works great, will accept if I don't find a cleaner solution that doesn't use reflection

Comment: @aryaxt happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
let a: Any = "5"
let b: Any? = "5"

if type(of: a) == Optional<Any>.self {
    print("a is optional")
} else {
    print("a is not optional")
}

if type(of: b) == Optional<Any>.self {
    print("b is optional")
} else {
    print("b is not optional")
}

/*
 a is not optional
 b is optional
*/
```

another example ...

```
let a: Any = 5
let b: Any? = 5
let c: Any = "5"
let d: Any? = "5"


let arr: [Any] = [a,b as Any,c,d as Any]
arr.forEach { (x) in
    print(type(of: x))
}

/*
 Int
 Optional<Any>
 String
 Optional<Any>
*/
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work withg the following input
```let a = "5"
,let b = Optional.some("5")`
```

Comment: @aryaxt because b from your example has type Optional<String>, check it with type(of: Optional.some("5"))

Comment: I need a dynamic solution that works all the time and covers all cases. @dfri's answer solves the problem

Comment: @aryaxt you wrote: "Given a value of type Any is it possible to check and see if it's an Optional or not?" I like dfri's solution, with a note, that Mirror could be customized and not all types are supported, so be careful

Comment: @user3441734 note any type at all that is an optional will produce `displayStyle` `optional` when reflected upon (even an optional collection, e.g. `[String]?`, will produce `displayStyle` `optional`), there is no limitation in the `Mirror` in that aspect. The limitation is that the `displayStyle` may return `nil` for wrapped values that are _not_ optionals, but then we know by exclusion that the value is not an optional (which was the intent).