# Nil checks not always working for Any in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm confused about how Swift checks for nil when I'm using the Any type.
Here's an example:

```
let testA: Any? = nil
let testB: Any = testA as Any
let testC: Any? = testB

if testA != nil {
    print(testA) // is not called as expected
}
if testB != nil {
    print(testB) // prints "nil"
}
if testC != nil {
    print(testC) // prints "Optional(nil)"
}
```

**testA** works as expected. The variable is nil, so the condition is false.

**testB** works not as expecte. The variable is nil, as shown by the print call. But the condition `testB != nil` evaluates to true. Why is this the case?

**testC** confuses me as well, since it is testC = testB = testA. So why should it behave differently than testA?

How would I need to write the if conditions `if testB ...` and `if testC ...` to not be true.
I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to know the type, like ...

```
if let testB = testB as String
```

**Edit:** I'm testing this with Swift 4 in an Xcode 9.1 Playground file.

**Edit2:**
Some information about the actual problem I want to solve.
I'm getting a dictionary of type `[String: Any?]` that is created by a JSON parser. I want to check if the value for a given key is nil, but it doesn't work, when the key exists and the value is Optional(nil).

Example:

```
var dict = [String: Any?]()
var string = "test"
var optionalString: String?
dict["key1"] = string
dict["key2"] = optionalString

if dict["key2"] != nil {
    print(dict["key2"]) // should not be executed, but returns Optional(nil)
}
```

Comment: It's weird that `let testB: Any = testA as Any` doesn't give any compiler errors in the first place. `testA` is an optional and `testB` is not, so  assigning `testA` to `testB` should at least tell you that it's not safe to do so and that you need to cast with `as?` or `as!`.

Comment: `let testB: Any = testA` should have warned you about the eroding of the optional type (which you then silenced by saying `as Any`). Basically the root problem you're dealing with here is that you can't treat something as an optional unless the compiler knows that it's an optional. Saying `let testC: Any? = testB` just makes the compiler implicitly wrap `testB` in another layer of optionality. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: It looks like anything can be cast to Any. Thus Any can be nil as well, as demonstrated above. The strange thing is that the `testB != nil` shows a warning `Comparing non-optional value of type 'Any' to nil always returns true`.

Comment: @Hamish I added some background information to the question.

Comment: @florieger Ah, in that case, you just want to unwrap twice. `if let value = dict["key"]` gives you `value` of type `Any?`, meaning that the dictionary had the value. If you then say `if let nonNilValue = value`, you'll get back an `Any`, meaning that the value itself was non-nil. You can also say `dict["key"] ?? nil` to condense the two layers of optionality into one. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/29299727/2976878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33049246/2976878

Comment: @Hamish this works for my second example, but not for `testB` and `testC`

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to cast Any to an Optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060818/is-it-possible-to-cast-any-to-an-optional) – Your `testB` is not an optional, and reflection is needed to "extract" the optional again.

Comment: Seconding what @MartinR writes (focusing on the contrived examples); also possibly [the following Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428796/given-a-swift-any-type-can-i-determine-if-its-an-optional) can be of interest, regarding using runtime introspection to query whether an `Any` instance wraps any kind of `Optional<...>` instance or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, nil is actually a concrete value(of type enum). `testB` which is of `Any` type, is holding the `enum Optional` with value `none` and hence the condition `testB != nil` is true.

[image]

This solves the mystery of how `Any` of `testB` is able to hold the nil value.

Coming to your actual problem, I tried this piece of code in Storyboard(Xcode 9.2) and it worked as expected.

```
var dict = [String: Any]()
var string = "test"
var optionalString: String?
dict["key1"] = string
dict["key2"] = optionalString

if let value = dict["key2"] {
    print(value) // doesn't get executed
}
```

For testB and testC, it seems like == check with nil should provide a solution but, because binary operand can not be used with two Any? operands, we can not use ==.

Using switch-case though is able to give correct results:

```
switch testB {
case Optional<Any>.none:
    print("value is none")
default:
    print("value is not none")
}

switch testC! {
case Optional<Any>.none:
    print("value is none")
default:
    print("value is not none")
}
```

**O/P**:
value is none
value is none

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution, how could I make it work with `testB` and `testC`.

Comment: @florieger: Updated the answer

Comment: So the same thing in memory can be interpreted in swift as nil in one case and as non-nil in another case? Absolutely insane language design decision.

Comment: @algrid: Its more of a Any type thing, but I agree its very confusing.

Comment: As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61530672/513038 , I think the problem actually occurs in `(Any) != nil` - the expression of compile-time type `Any` is, at compile time, wrapped in another layer of `Optional` - so the first layer of `Optional` is non-`nil`, and it contains an `Optional` which IS `nil`.  (Technically `.none`.)  At runtime, the `String?` is wrapped to become a `String??`.  Maybe go read the linked answer, if my comment doesn't make sense.